# Duplicate OrderIDs

Tags: expresso-store, devdemon

I’m running a few sites using Expresso Store (2.5.1) and the traffic and volume of sales of one of them has increased dramatically in the past month.

Unfortunately we’ve had two instances where the two orders have shared an OrderID which is playing havoc with our warehouse system. In both cases the orders have obviously come in at a very similar (but not identical) time. In the most recent instance the orders (according to the store order summary screen came in at:

2/2/2017 10:46 AM
and
2/2/2017 10:45 AM

Any advice you have on how to prevent this or a patch available would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

(I've with Vector; [we acquired Exp-resso Store a few weeks ago](https://www.vectormediagroup.com/blog/view/vector-has-acquired-devdemon-and-expresso-store).)

Have you checked what your database load was like at this time? This kind of thing can happen if database load is high and so queries get blocked and end up seeing some stale data about the most recent order #.

There are potentially some patches to try to avoid this, but I'd definitely start with making sure database capacity is high enough that it doesn't get into a backed up state with queries getting stalled. Did you see high database load and slow queries during this time?